# emacs marmalade: "Cannot open load file", "package"

Tags: emacs, elisp, marmalade

I'm using emacs 24 and would like to install marmalade.

I've tried adding the following to my `~/.emacs` file, as per the instructions on http://marmalade-repo.org/:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives 
    '("marmalade" .
      "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize)
```

When I try to reload e-macs I get the error:

```
Error in init file: File error: "Cannot open load file", "package".
```

What might be wrong?

Comment: What happens if you interactively type `M-x package-initialize`?

Comment: Don't know much about Emacs, I'd prefer direct dmg install ;-)

Comment: I was using emacs 22 not 24. I deserve downvotes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sounds like your version of Emacs does not come with library `package.el`. Does `M-x find-library package` find it? If not, you can try downloading it from the web (maybe start with Emacs Wiki), and then putting it in your `load-path`.

But even in that case it might not work with your Emacs version.

Comment: (I'm a bit surprised by the downvote, 4 years later. Care to explain?)

Answer (score 7):

I got this message when I installed the latest emacs (26) from homebrew, and ran it.  The problem was that OS X comes with a really old emacs (22).  That was what was running when I ran emacs.

I assume that the new emacs wasn't linked in my current terminal.  I fixed this problem by just opening a new terminal and running emacs from there.

Comment: how do I do this?

Answer (score 4):

I had this error message after I'd switched from macports to homebrew package management on the mac.

I suspect I'd installed emacs using macports, and although it was still available after removing macports, I may have removed the libraries I was relying on. Installing the newest version of emacs via homebrew fixed the problem.

Re-install emacs if you think you might have done something similarly foolish.